# How to make this table just with HTML

Tags: html, web, html-table, tags

I want to make this table just with **HTML**.
Please Help Me.

[This Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNclj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `colspan="2"` :

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ldDV6v9.jpg" width="50px" /></th>
    <th>Item 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Third Item</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><a href="http://example.com">Forth Item</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```